# How to pass a parameter to a function and then use that in function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a reusable Table Component, Where I pass (headerArray, dataArrayObject, addEditButton ) as an props from parent component.

Table is well created with the code written below.

> ```
> const Table = ({tableData,headingColumns,addEditButton}) => {
>     const onEditHandler = (rowDetail) =>{
>         console.log(rowDetail);
>         console.log("clicked");
>     }  
>     const data = tableData.map((row,index) =>{
>         let rowData = [];
>         let i = 0;
>         for(const key in row){
>            rowData.push({
>               key:headingColumns[i],
>               val:row[key] 
>            }) 
>            i++;
>         }
>         return <tr key = {index}>
>             {rowData.map((data,index) =>
>             <td key = {index} data-heading = {data.key}>{data.val}</td>)}
>             {addEditButton && 
>             <td>
>                 <button className = "btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" 
>       onClick ={(row)=>onEditHandler(row)}>
>       <EditIcon color="secondary"/>
>       </button>
>             </td>}       
>         </tr>
>     })
>     return (
>         <div className = "table-container">            
>             <table
>        className = {tableClass} 
>       style = {{backgroundColor :"rgba(0,0,0,0.4)",fontSize : "12px"}}>
>                 <thead>
>                     <tr>
>                         {headingColumns.map((col,index)=>(
>                             <th key = {index}>{col}</th> 
>                         ))}
>                     </tr>
>                 </thead>
>                 <tbody>
>                     {data}
>                 </tbody>
>             </table>
>         </div>
>     )
> }
> ```

But, problem is on onEditHandler, Where I want to pass the data of the particular  as an parameter on onClick function, which i call on function I am not receiving the data which i was expecting an object instead recieve a SyntheticBaseEvent as an Value of Parameter passed.
[image]  .

While i got function works fine as i also get Clicked console i have mentioned in function.

Comment: Hi! what did you expect to receive?

Comment: `(row)=>onEditHandler(row)` this line passes the click event to the `onEditHandler`. Try: `()=>onEditHandler(row)`

Comment: @alisasani : an object of particular row -{id : "",foodItem : "",foodPrice : ""}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a higher order function like this:

```
const onEditHandler = rowDetail => nativeEvent => {
    console.log(rowDetail);
    console.log(nativeEvent);
}
```

Then in the JSX:

```
onClick={onEditHandler(row)}
```

Other solution: just don't give a name to the callback parameter so that `row` refers to the `row` you're expecting:

```
onClick={() => onEditHandler(row)}
```

Comment: wouldn't this execute the function onload?

Comment: @boxdox yes it would, but it would also return another `function`